# How to get a selected listviewitem from a custom WPF listview for routed event when using Elmish.WPF?

Tags: listview, routed-events, elmish-wpf

I'm a newbie to Elmish.

The WPF binding uses the custom control as:

```
local:AppointmentListView.ScheduledAppointment ="AppointmentDataGrid_ScheduledAppointment"
```

I have a C# custom ListView that raises the following routed event when a listview item is selected:

```
private void AppointmentListView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem;
            if ((IVisit)item != null)
            {
                ScheduledAppointmentEventArgs args = new ScheduledAppointmentEventArgs(ScheduledAppointmentEvent, (IVisit)item);
                RaiseEvent(args);
            }   
        }
```

I do not need the C# casting of "IVisit", but I DO NEED the selected listview item to be of Visit type from the F# model. That is, I need the actual object appointment key. But what I am getting is:
*"Elmish.WPF.ViewModel<object, object>"*

The itemsSource for the ListView is defined as "AppointmentKeys" in Elmish.WPF as:

```
type Model =
    { AppointmentKeys: Visit.Model list
      Id: int
    }

let bindings() =[
    "AppointmentKeys"  |> Binding.subModelSeq(
                            (fun (_, m) -> m.AppointmentKeys),
                            (fun v -> v.Id),
                             Visit.bindings                            
                          )
```

So, the question is: **In the code behind, how do I return the F# record selected by the user from the ListView?**

**More specifically, how is the F# code written to return the selected list view item when the "SelectedItem" comes from the code-behind binding on MouseButtonEvents?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't subscribe to events with a function defined in your code-behind.  Instead, convert the event into a command [like this](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/blob/bd74fd68dcc5cdbf12f98341c76945c663d837bf/src/Samples/EventBindingsAndBehaviors.Views/MainWindow.xaml#L22) from the [`EventBindingsAndBehaviors` sample](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/EventBindingsAndBehaviors).  Then binding to a selected item from a `ListView` as in done in the [`SubModelSelectedItem` sample](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/SubModelSelectedItem).